# Camel route fan out to multiple destination dynamically

Tags: apache-camel

When using the Recipient list to a multiple dynamic list of endpoints can I collect the response back from all the final destinations selected ?
What I would like to do is fan out to a dynamic list of endpoints with inout exchange pattern.
I don't what to use the split-agreegate EIP because I would like to stream back responses as they come available and the aggregate waits for all the results to arrive.

http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Thank you, kindly﻿

Comment: Use the aggregation strategy on the recipient list

Comment: The aggregator doesn't have to wait for all the responses to come back. You can set timeout on it. For example, you can set up the aggregator to aggregate messages in batches of X messages but also have a timeout of Y seconds. If X number of message don't arrive in Y seconds then the aggregator will automatically aggregate the messages it's received so far.